# Does compiling a Python script using Cython reduce start up time?

Tags: python, cython

It is known that python programs start a little slow. Does compiling whole program with cython solve this problem?

Comment: Have you profiled your code to see *why* it's slow to start up?

Comment: `cython` is meant to give you modules that you can import and use with regular Python code.  You use it speed up selected core functions, not the whole code.  It's not a replacement for the Python interpreter or your basic script.

Comment: I am trying to decide technology i will use for a mobile project. E.g. python and kivi or something else. Hence i do not have code yet. I saw in an answer here that the whole programs CAN be compiled by cython. That is the reason i asked the question.

Comment: Can you give a link for that claim that it can compile a whole program?  `cython` creates one or more `c` files, which are then compiled with your system `c` compiler.  Throw `kivi` and mobile platforms into the mix, and you've got yourself some serious system coding.  Forget about `cython` and speed for now, and work on the `kivi` and mobile end.

Comment: @hpaulj You can compile a whole Python program with Cython  https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython

Comment: A quick glance at the `kivy` website shows the it uses `cython` (requires).  Also it has the tools for creating an `APK`.