# How to make in exe application from C codes generated by Cython using cl compiler on windows 7

Tags: python, c, windows, visual-studio, cython

I would like to port a linux GUI program to window.
but before I do this, I am trying to port a python "hello_world" script to c codes and then compile the c does to exe

Here is how I port the python codes to c using cython on windows 7

```
cython --embed -o hello.c hello.py
```

Now I am trying to compile the C codes using the cl compiler in visual studio on the **Developer Command Prompt**  and also on windows **command prompt** as follows

```
cl  /IC:\Python27\include\ /c hello.c  /OUT hello
```

The above make a `hello.obj` file

Now the linking part seems a little painful. Here is how I link

```
cl hello.obj -LIBPATH C:\Python27\libs\*    /MACHINE:X64
```

But I got the following errors below

```
/out:hello.exe
hello.obj
C:\Python27\libs\bz2.lib
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a
C:\Python27\libs\pyexpat.lib
C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib
C:\Python27\libs\select.lib
C:\Python27\libs\unicodedata.lib
C:\Python27\libs\winsound.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_bsddb.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_ctypes.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_ctypes_test.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_elementtree.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_hashlib.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_msi.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_multiprocessing.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_socket.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_sqlite3.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_ssl.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_testcapi.lib
C:\Python27\libs\_tkinter.lib
   Creating library hello.lib and object hello.exp
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyMem_Malloc refere
nced in function ___pyx_insert_code_object
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyMem_Realloc refer
enced in function ___pyx_insert_code_object
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyObject_SetAttrStr
ing referenced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_FromS
tringAndSize referenced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyUnicodeUCS2_Decod
eUTF8 referenced in function ___Pyx_InitStrings
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromString
AndSize referenced in function ___Pyx_InitStrings
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromString
 referenced in function ___Pyx_CreateCodeObjectForTraceback
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_FromFormat
 referenced in function ___Pyx_CreateCodeObjectForTraceback
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_Size refer
enced in function ___Pyx_Print
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_AsString r
eferenced in function ___Pyx_Print
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyString_InternFrom
String referenced in function ___Pyx_InitStrings
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyTuple_New referen
ced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_New referenc
ed in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyDict_SetItem refe
renced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyModule_GetDict re
ferenced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFile_WriteObject
referenced in function ___Pyx_Print
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFile_SoftSpace re
ferenced in function ___Pyx_Print
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFile_WriteString
referenced in function ___Pyx_Print
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyTraceBack_Here re
ferenced in function ___Pyx_AddTraceback
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_WarnEx refere
nced in function ___Pyx_check_binary_version
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_SetString ref
erenced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Occurred refe
renced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Clear referen
ced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyOS_snprintf refer
enced in function ___Pyx_check_binary_version
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_InitModule4 refe
renced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_SetProgramName r
eferenced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Initialize refer
enced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_Finalize referen
ced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyErr_Print referen
ced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_GetVersion refer
enced in function ___Pyx_check_binary_version
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Py_FlushLine refere
nced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PySys_GetObject ref
erenced in function ___Pyx_GetStdout
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PySys_SetArgv refer
enced in function _main
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyImport_AddModule
referenced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyCode_New referenc
ed in function ___Pyx_CreateCodeObjectForTraceback
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyFrame_New referen
ced in function ___Pyx_AddTraceback
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_ImportError r
eferenced in function _initpy
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PyExc_RuntimeError
referenced in function ___Pyx_GetStdout
hello.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___PyThreadState_Curr
ent referenced in function ___Pyx_AddTraceback
C:\Python27\libs\bz2.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts
 with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' con
flicts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\pyexpat.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' confl
icts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\python27.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conf
licts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\select.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' confli
cts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\unicodedata.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' c
onflicts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\winsound.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conf
licts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_bsddb.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' confli
cts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_ctypes.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' confl
icts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_ctypes_test.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64'
conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_elementtree.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64'
conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_hashlib.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conf
licts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_msi.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflict
s with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_multiprocessing.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x
64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_socket.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' confl
icts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_sqlite3.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conf
licts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_ssl.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflict
s with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_testcapi.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' con
flicts with target machine type 'X86'
C:\Python27\libs\_tkinter.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conf
licts with target machine type 'X86'
hello.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 39 unresolved externals
```

Kindly excuse my ignorance in certain aspects of the C language.

How can I make a .exe from hello.c which is generated from cython on windows 7?

Comment: Well, for a start, `cl` is the compiler, not the linker.  Assuming that's a typo, the `/LIBPATH` argument should point to a directory, i.e., just `C:\Python27\libs` not `C:\Python27\libs\*`.

Comment: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307793/does-compiling-a-python-script-using-cython-reduce-start-up-time

Comment: @HarryJohnston I tried taking out that asterik from  "C:\Python27\libs\*"  but this just give me a fatal error "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Python27\libs.obj'"...hmmm....

Comment: Sounds as though it is treating the argument as an input file.  Try correcting the syntax, [according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xhzskbe.aspx) it should be `/LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs` rather than `-LIBPATH C:\Python27\libs`